# combining multiple rows into a single column and finding differences

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with two columns stated as below

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-18 | 12 |
| 2021-08-18 | 15 |
| 2021-08-18 | 10 |
| 2021-08-19 | 15 |
| 2021-08-19 | 10 |
| 2021-08-20 | 15 |
| 2021-08-20 | 10 |
| 2021-08-20 | 14 |

- On 2021-08-19, [15,10] are the id's
- On 2021-08-18, [12,15,10] are the id's
- Two columns 'A' and 'B' are to be added
- 'A' column for 2021-08-19 in each row should have number of elements in [12,15,10]-[15,10](mathematics set subtraction, id's in set1 but not in set 2), which will result in 1 (which is previous day all id's minus current day all id's]
- 'B' column for 2021-08-19 in each row should have number of elements in [15,10]-[12,15,10] (mathematics set subtraction, id's in set1 but not in set2), which will result in 0 (which is current day all id's minus previous day all id's]

How do I achieve this in pyspark (Even a sql will be fine)

expected output:

| date | id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-18 | 12 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-08-18 | 15 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-08-18 | 10 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-08-19 | 15 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-19 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-20 | 15 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-08-20 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-08-20 | 14 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a new dataframe which we'll join back to the other dataframe. First we groupby the date and collect the elements into a list and get their size. Then we add a column using a window which gets the previous size and create two columns doing the substractions.

Then we have `df2` and we join it back to the original dataframe.

See below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([
    ("2021-08-18", 12,),
    ("2021-08-18", 15,),
    ("2021-08-18", 10,),
    ("2021-08-19", 15,),
    ("2021-08-19", 10,),
    ("2021-08-20", 15,),
    ("2021-08-20", 10,),
    ("2021-08-20", 14,),
], columns=["date", "id"]))


w = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy("date")

def negative_to_zero(col):
    return F.when(col < 0, 0).otherwise(col)


df2 = (
    df.groupby("date")
    .agg(
        F.size(F.collect_list("id")).alias("size"),
    )
    .withColumn("previous", F.coalesce(F.lag("size").over(w), F.lit(0)))
    .withColumn("size", F.coalesce(F.col("size"), F.lit(0)))
    .select(
        "date",
        negative_to_zero(F.col("previous") - F.col("size")).alias("A"),
        negative_to_zero(F.col("size") - F.col("previous")).alias("B"),
    )
)

df.join(
    df2, 
    how="left", 
    on="date"
).orderBy("date").show()
```

Potentially it can be simplified further using only windows, but this works.

```
+----------+---+---+---+
|      date| id|  A|  B|
+----------+---+---+---+
|2021-08-18| 12|  0|  3|
|2021-08-18| 10|  0|  3|
|2021-08-18| 15|  0|  3|
|2021-08-19| 10|  1|  0|
|2021-08-19| 15|  1|  0|
|2021-08-20| 15|  0|  1|
|2021-08-20| 14|  0|  1|
|2021-08-20| 10|  0|  1|
+----------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks @Thijs ,what you posted was not exactly what i was looking but it helped me to get what is required